# How to retrieve active value from slicer in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, slicers

I would like to retrieve the selected value from an activated slicer in Excel so I can use it in a formule. How would I do this? I've been playing around with the ActiveItem from the Slicer object using the Microsoft VBA help site but I'm not to familiar with the VBA syntax.

What I would like to achieve is that the value in the selected cell is equal to the selected value in the Slicer named ("Slicer_Organisatie___Tariefgroep")

I've tried it with the following code using the guidelines on the following site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.slicer.activeitem

```vb
Sub TestSelectActiveSlicer()
'
' TestSelectActiveSlicer Macro
'
    Range("H5").Select
    ActiveCell = Slicer.ActiveItem


End Sub
```

When I run the macro I get the following error:
Run-time error '424':
Object required

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried thusfar?  It may be a simply issue with qualifying, or it could be need for a new line... should help us better understand what is occurring (or that is, what is "not" occurring).

Comment: Hi Cyril, I've added the code that I've tried, does this help?